# Given a non-symmetric matrix, find conic equation

Tags: linear-transformations, conic-sections

Consider the matrix
$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1/2 & -2 
\end{pmatrix}.$

How do you find the ellipse equation in terms of $x$ and $y?$

I have
$X =  x+y, \;Y=-\frac{x}{2}-2y.$

Then do we assume $\;X^2 + Y^2 = 1\;$ and $\;X^2 = \frac{x^2}{p^2}, Y^2 = \frac{y^2}{q^2}?$
Why?

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+y)^2+\left( \frac{x}{2}+2y \right)^2=1 \implies \frac{5x^2}{4}+4xy+5y^2=1$$